# How to just install app without building everytime

Tags: android, build, installation, android-studio

I want to install a developing app to some emulators and devices for testing.

Just press run, android studio will make, build and then install. It seems useless to make and build everytime if I don't modify code. And building will cost much time.

So, how to just install app without building everytime.

Comment: Just beacuse it builds, it doesn't mean that it will rebuild everything from scratches. Bytecode generated from unmodified source files is kept from one build to another.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo "Bytecode generated from unmodified source files" is not always kept. There are quite many conditions that lead to a recompilation of more than just the changed files.

Comment: @justlerning conditions like? [ANT](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#always-recompiles) and [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#staleMillis) (the two common choices in IntelliJ/AndroidStudio) both recompile files based on timestamps. Let's ignore settings that force recompilation and `touch`ing files, because that is quite not a simple rebuild.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Imagine a `public class A` which contains `public int foo()`. `class B` calls `instanceOfA.foo()` but pops the return value. Then you change `foo` to `public String foo()`. The source of `B` is still valid, but not the bytecode which still points to `int foo()`.

Comment: @justlerning "Then you change"... well, you are changing files.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes, but only one file which requires the recompilation of two files. "Bytecode generated from unmodified source files is kept from one build to another." Source file for `class B` is unmodified but it must be recompiled. But I agree, builds don't require a complete rebuild. **Edit**: I might have misunderstood your statement. If that's the case, I am sorry.

Comment: From my experience rebuilding an app that hasn't been changed is extremely fast, so I assume it skips a lot of the build process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to just install the apk:

```
adb install -r PATH/TO/PROJECT/build/apk/PROJECT-(release|debug).apk
```

Comment: That's it. Everything is in documentation http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Android Studio, open the Terminal window.

Then:

```
adb install -r app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

This is a slightly different path than shown in the accepted answer, which may be due to updates in Android Studio's build path. In an example project where a normal build/run takes 30-60 seconds, this took about 1 second in comparison. If the app was already running, it will exit and can be run from its icon in the device OS.